# Building library from source files in Unix-like OS

Tags: linux, macos, unix, makefile

When building any library from sources files, is it possible to set the place where I want it to be installed? I have read about some `prefix` flag, but I was wondering if all aplications have that flag.

For instance, I was building OpenCV from sources and when I made `make && make install` the contents where installed in `/usr/local/opencv` but what If I want it to be installed in `/other/place/opencv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, that stuff is done during the *configure phase* with something like:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/other/place/opencv
```

If the project doesn't have a `configure` script then it's a case of editing the `Makefile` directly.

Comment: Yes I was wondering that. So if there's a configure file I can always change the prefix right? If there's no configure I can always check the Makefile and fix it as I need according to what you say.

Comment: @BRabbit27 Not always, but 99.9% of the time.  It's really up to the authors to expose whatever properties they like.